# Groovy create map from lines of text

Tags: parsing, dictionary, groovy

I have raw data that is contained in 3 separate lines. I want to build a single map record using parts of each line. I then read the next 3 lines and create the next map record and so on. All the groovy examples I've found on maps show them being created from data on a single line, or possibly i am misunderstanding the examples. Here is what the raw data looks like.

```
snmp v2: data result = "Local1"
snmp v2: data result ip = "10.10.10.121"
snmp v2: data result gal = "899"
new
snmp v2: data result = "Local2"
snmp v2: data result ip = "192.168.10.2"
snmp v2: data result gal = "7777"
new
```

I want to put this data into a map. In this example Local1 and Local2 would be keys and they would each have 2 associated values. I will show you my latest attempt but it is little more then a guess that failed.

```
def data = RAW
def map = [:]
data.splitEachLine("="){
 it.each{ x ->
 map.put(it[0], it[1])

 map.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" } }}
```

The desired output is:

```
[ Local1 : [ ip: "10.10.10.121", gal: "899" ], 
Local2: [ ip: "192.168.10.2", gal: "7777" ] ]
```

Comment: What do you want the map to look like? Do you have an example of the output you'd expect from the above input?

Comment: I suppose the expectation is `[ Local1 : [ ip: "10.10.10.121", gal: "899" ], Local2: [ ip: "192.168.10.2", gal: "7777" ] ]` @tim_yates

Comment: The comment  from dmahapatro is how the output should look. The name of the office being the key and the ip and gal as values associated with the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a nested map as suggested by dmahapatro try this:

```
def map = [:]

data=data.eachLine() { line ->
  if(line.startsWith("new")) return
  tokens=line.replace("snmp v2: data","").split("=")
  tokens=tokens.collect() { it.trim().replace("result ","").replaceAll(/"/, "") }
  if(tokens[0]=="result") {
      nested=[:]
      map[tokens[1]]=nested
  }
  else
      nested[tokens[0]]=tokens[1]
}
println("map: $map")
```

here we:

- iterate over lines
- skip lines with "new" at the beginning
- remove "snmp v2: data" from the text of the line
- split each line in tokens, trim() each token, and remove "result " and quotes
  tokens are in pairs and now look like:

  result, Local1

  ip, 10.10.10.121

  gal, 899
- next when the first token is "result", we build a nested map and place in the main map at the key given by the value of token[1]
- otherwise we populate the nested map with key=token[0] and value=token[1]

the result is:

```
map: [Local1:[ip:10.10.10.121, gal:899], Local2:[ip:192.168.10.2, gal:7777]]
```

edit: fixed to remove quotes

Answer (score 2):

You can build a new data structure from an existing one using aggregate operations defined on collections; collect produces a list from an existing list, collectEntries creates a map from a list.

The question specifies there are always three lines for an entry, followed by a line with "new" on it. If I can assume they're always in the same order I can grab the last word off each line, use collate to group every four lines into a sublist, then convert each sublist to a map entry:

```
lines = new File('c:/temp/testdata.txt').readLines()
mymap = lines.collect { it.tokenize()[-1] }
  .collate(4)
  .collectEntries { e-> [(e[0].replace('"', ''))) : [ip: e[1], gal: e[2]]] }
```

which evaluates to

```
[Local1:[ip:"10.10.10.121", gal:"899"], Local2:[ip:"192.168.10.2", gal:"7777"]]
```

or remove all the quotes in the first step:

```
mymap = lines.collect { (it.tokenize()[-1]).replace('"', '') }
  .collate(4)
  .collectEntries { e-> [(e[0]) : [ip: e[1], gal: e[2]]] }
```

in order to get

```
[Local1:[ip:10.10.10.121, gal:899], Local2:[ip:192.168.10.2, gal:7777]]
```